# SQL Insert over VPN has strange results

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am not sure if I'm doing something wrong? Whenever I connect to the office wifi and test my apps registration features, the email section shows a different result from my input. Example if I enter test@test.com and the go into phpmyadmin to check, it will be test@nefiewx.legsq.nl3.gsr.awhoer.net. Is something wrong with my code or do I have to avoid using the wifi?

I had to use a vpn to access my phpmyadmin but I see that some of the address in the URL is similar to what has been entered into the database.

This is my insert code. Thank you

```
<?php

    include '../configuration/credentials.php';
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
        if($conn->connect_error){
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
        $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
        $dateofbirth = $_POST["dateofbirth"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $phone = $_POST["phone"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($firstname));
        $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($lastname));
        $dateofbirth = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($dateofbirth));
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($email));
        $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($phone));
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($password));

        $checkuserexistsquery = "SELECT email, phone FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND phone='$phone'";
        $insertuserquery = "INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,dateofbirth,phone,email,password) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$dateofbirth','$phone','$email','$password')";
        $checkuserexistsresults = mysqli_query($conn,$checkuserexistsquery);
        if($checkuserexistsresults===FALSE){
            echo "Check user query failed";
        }else{
            $countcheckuserexistsresults = mysqli_num_rows($checkuserexistsresults);
            if($countcheckuserexistsresults>0){
                //user already exists
                echo "User already exists";
                while($row = $checkuserexistsresults->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo $row['email'];
                    echo $row['phone'];
                }

            }else{
                //user doesn't exist
                $insertuserresults = mysqli_query($conn,$insertuserquery);
                if($insertuserresults===FALSE){
                    echo "Insert user query failed";
                }else{
                    echo "Insert successful";
                }
            }
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }

?>
```

Hope I can get help with this

Comment: On a side note, you are very prone to SQL Injections.

Comment: Yeah I've been wanting to change the insert methods for awhile now. I am trying to solve this weird issue first though

Comment: I wonder if your office has some appliance that is intercepting your request and "correcting" the email address. I'd do some tests, just echo directly `$_POST["email"]` and see how it changes when on wifi, off the wifi, and when on wifi but connecting via SSL. Try a variety of email addresses, not just your company domain. Ask your network administrator if they have any idea why this might happen. Try using GET instead of POST just to narrow down the problem.